# Could not find method include() [product]

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I am moving from maven to gradle. In maven I have several modules included:

I should just write `dependsOn 'product-api'` correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add modules to `settings.gradle`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds).

#### settings.gradle

```
include 'product-rating-storage-api'
include 'product-rating-storage-ignite'
include 'product-rating-client-api'
```

Comment: You should only add the module list in `settings.gradle`. Rest should stay in `build.gradle`.